# explicit casting of object containing array - to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, object, casting, implicit

The short version -

Is there an **easy** way to take a variable of type **object** containing an instance of an **unknown array** (UInt16[], string[], etc.) and treat it as an array, say call String.Join(",", obj) to produce a comma delimited string?

Trivial?  I thought so too.

Consider the following:

```
object obj = properties.Current.Value;
```

obj might contain different instances - an array for example, say UInt16[], string[], etc.

I want to treat obj as the type that it is, namely - perform a cast to an unknown type.  After I accomplish that, I will be able to continue normally, namely:

```
Type objType = obj.GetType();
string output = String.Join(",", (objType)obj);
```

The above code, of course, does not work (objType unknown).

Neither does this:

```
object[] objArr = (object[])obj;   (Unable to cast exception)
```

Just to be clear - I am not trying to convert the object to an array (it's already an instance of an array), just be able to treat it as one.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to convert the object to IEnumerable

Comment: Maybe you can replace `object obj = properties.Current.Value;` by `dynamic obj = properties.Current.Value;` then treat `obj` as an `array`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 4 (where [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx) gained more overloads) or later there are two simple options:

- Use dynamic typing to get the compiler to work out the generic type argument:

  ```
  dynamic obj = properties.Current.Value;
  string output = string.Join(",", obj);
  ```
- Cast to `IEnumerable`, then use `Cast<object>` to get an `IEnumerable<object>`:

  ```
  IEnumerable obj = (IEnumerable) properties.Current.Value;
  string output = string.Join(",", obj.Cast<object>());
  ```

Comment: You are my god!  Thank you :-)